# How to "use" local "defs" in SVG

Tags: html, svg

I have multiple SVG pictures embedded into single HTML page.
Every SVG has own `defs` section that I am referencing to in my `use` elements.
It looks like I can't define element with the same id inside multiple `defs` and reference to it.
Second SVG `use` will pick the definition form the first SVG `defs` section, and ignore the local redefinition.

Does anybody know how I can reference to the LOCAL `defs` section?

The same story in Chrome and Firefox.

1. See the example below:

   ```
   <html><head></head><body>
   <svg height="50" width="50">
    <defs>
     <rect id="mybox" height="40" width="40" style="fill:#00F;"></rect>
    </defs> 
    <use xlink:href="#mybox"/>
   </svg>
   <svg height="50" width="50">
    <defs>
     <rect id="mybox" height="20" width="20" style="fill:#F00;"></rect>
    </defs> 
    <use xlink:href="#mybox"/>
   </svg>
   </body></html>
   ```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An SVG file with multiple identical IDs is invalid per http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#IDAttribute

Your options are either make all the IDs unique or move the SVG into separate files and reference them via `<object>` or `<iframe>` tags.

Comment: I can't use external SVG files. because I generate SVGs inside the page using javaScript. [my code](http://wavedrom.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tutorial.html). It is difficult to make all IDs unique; so I was thinking about scoping `defs` inside every `<SVG>` embedded inside `<HTML>` document. But it looks flat.

Comment: The problem is not multiple identical IDs in an SVG file, but multiple inline SVGs in an HTML file, that happens to use the same ID in their defs section. IDs won't collide if the SVGs are external, only if they are inline. Surprising, I would expect ID to be unique inside an SVG. But kind of makes sense since they all will be part of the same DOM when they are inlined in the HTML. Annoying though.

Answer (score 2):

I created a tool to randomize definition id's to avoid this issue with inline svg's referencing the same #id, hopefully it will be useful for someone else. http://hugozap.com/randomize_svg_def_ids.html

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is using [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo)

```
svgo --enable=prefixIds *.svg
```

svgo can be installed via npm and is available as a library as well